# Was the scene depicting a Commons vote won by 3/4 of a vote real in "This House"?

Tags: united-kingdom, house-of-commons, speaker

["This House"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_House_(play)) features a scene where a vote in the Commons is practically tied, but then the Speaker decides that one of the parties' case is stronger and says that they win by 3/4 of a vote.

I've not found references (on Google & Wikipedia) to such a possible vote in the 70's, but perhaps I don't know the right keywords. Most of the contextual events in "This House" seem to be based in history, if chronologically re-arranged, so I would have thought that this vote also happened -- though it's difficult to track down.

**Did this vote -- where the Speaker 'awarded' a 3/4 vote to one of the parties -- really happen, and, if so, why did he do that?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The part of the play which I believe you're referring to can be read [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jw77DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA83#v=onepage&q&f=false), and refers to the actions of Walter Harrison, then a government whip in a *committee stage* vote, not a vote in the main Commons chamber.

> **Serjeant**
>
> Please. Mr Speaker, there's been a difference of opinion regarding the
>   votes on two bills at committee stage. Amendments to the Education
>   Bill were being voted on in Committee Room 10, while amendments to the
>   Finance Bill were being voted on in Committee Room 14. Mr Harrison
>   here had been the pre-selected Whip present at both committees -
>
> **Harrison**
>
> Yes, right, I voted in 14 and then I ran down the corridor to 10 to
>   vote there and -
>
> **Serjeant**
>
> Just as I was closing the door.
>
> **Atkins**
>
> Just as the doors were being closed, and locked, as is the custom -
>
> **Weatherill**
>
> As is the *law*. Committee room doors must be closed and locked during
>   a vote and -
>
> **Atkins**
>
> And he didn't make it -
>
> **Harrison**
>
> And I *did* bloody make it!
>
> **Serjeant**
>
> A sizeable chunk of Mr Harrison *did* make it, Mr Speaker.
>
> **Cocks / Harrison**
>
> See.
>
> **Speaker**
>
> Si - a 'sizeable' chunk, you say? Which chunk?
>
> **Harrison**
>
> My whole body, both arms, and my left leg, but my right leg got caught
>   in the door as he was closing it. Look, I've got a bruise and
>   everything -
>
> **Atkins**
>
> And then he wouldn't leave so that the doors could be closed -
>
> **Harrison**
>
> Because I'd made it into the room. Look at that, see, purple, like a
>   peach. Ouch.
>
> **Speaker**
>
> What was the vote *without* Mr Harrison?
>
> **Cocks / Serjeant**
>
> 22 to 22.
>
> **Speaker**
>
> Serjeant, would you say that the overwhelming majority of Mr Harrison
>   was *inside* the committee room?
>
> **Serjeant**
>
> Well. Uh, yes, I suppose I would, Mr Speaker.
>
> **Speaker**
>
> Very well, I declare the vote for the government, 22 to 22 *and three
>   quarters*.

The committee stage is where changes to the text of a bill are made, and happens between the second and third readings of the bill being voted on in the main Chamber. This specific instance is described further in the obituary of Walter Harrison in the [Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/obituaries/9626444/Walter-Harrison.html):

> One day in May 1968 he was whipping on two Committees at once when a
>   vote was called on the Finance Bill. He arrived just as the door was
>   closing, forced his way through and voted. When the Shadow Chancellor
>   Iain Macleod challenged his vote, Harrison said he had been
>   three-quarters in and had pulled his leg in after him. The chairman
>   declared the vote carried by 22¾ to 22.

So this *is* a fairly accurate historical account. However, in reality, the Speaker was not involved, the person who made the decision was the chairman of the bill committee, and he did so not because he thought the government's political case was strongest, but because he thought that Harrison got the majority of his body through the door before it was locked.